# What is the meaning 'language' as a verb?

Tags: meaning-in-context, usage

In the following sentence:

> Trump's tweet came days after the Republican Party's Platform Committee unanimously agreed **to language** on Israel that omits references to a two-state solution with the Palestinians.

([at jpost](http://www.jpost.com/US-Elections/Trump-Is-President-Obama-trying-to-destroy-Israel-with-all-his-bad-moves-460355))
what's the meaning of the verb 'language' in that context ?

Comment: You could rephrase the sentence as "unanimously approved to use language on Israel". As far as this sentence in particular, I would guess that language is a noun, but I can't attest to the grammatical correctness of it.

Comment: People are always seeking new ways to say something and I suppose this is one such example; however, it is not always true that a new way of saying something necessarily improves comprehensivity.

Comment: It's a noun in this sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrasal verb "agree to something" [means to accept something](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/agree-to-sth). The thing that is being accepted is "language that omits....."

So you have mis-parsed this sentence. The word "to" is part of a phrasal verb "agree to", not part of an infinitive "to language". The word "language" is used as a noun.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually not a verb, it's a noun. It is saying

> agreed to a particular form of words
>
> agreed to a particular choice of language

They have agreed to talk about Israel in a way that avoids certain phrases and formulations that are deemed contentious..